# APS / Forge Viewer get only un hidden geometry dbid

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to get only the dbid of loaded elements, currently the function i have gets all visible elements dbid.when using selective loading it shows all the none loaded element as visible and when i run get dbid function it gives me all the dbid in the db rather than only what is physically loaded in that instance of the viewer.

Could someone please advice the most efficient method of doing this in the viewer ?

Thanks in advance,
tom

EDITED

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a method to get visibles elements, but `getHiddenNodes()` method returns the list of hidden dbIds.

So one way to get the visible nodes could be:

- get all **dbIds** (here is a similar question where you can find a recursive function to find all **dbIds** in objects tree: [Get only visible objects in viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135410/how-to-get-dbid-of-only-visible-objects-in-viewer?rq=2))
- get hidden nodes with `viewer.getHiddenNodes()`
- filter visible nodes:

```
var visibleDbIds = allDbIds.filter(dbid => !hiddenNodes.includes(dbid))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i have worded my question poorly, i have used selective loading to only load geometry that meets a certain criteria. the problem im having is even though its not loading the geometry its still showing as visible. so what im really after is the dbid of loaded geometry rather than visible. i will edit my post.