# How to get dbId of visible objects in model viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I already tried this two answers: [How to get dbId of only visible objects in Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135410/how-to-get-dbid-of-only-visible-objects-in-viewer?rq=2) and [APS / Forge Viewer get only un hidden geometry dbid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271715/aps-forge-viewer-get-only-un-hidden-geometry-dbid/77274146#77274146) but nothing worked. The first answer code gives me a list of all objects dbIds in model, not all visible, and the second seems to complement de first one, but the function `viewer.getHiddenNodes()` doesn't work like it should, example:

[image: example]

Only walls are visible and:

[image: example2]

How do I get only the visible objects dbIds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model Structure panel calls [viewer.isolate( dbIds )](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#isolate-node-model) when clicking on the tree node. So, please use [viewer.getIsolatedNodes()](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#getisolatednodes-model) instead.

if you just get few dbIds inside, then it means you clicked on the supper node on the tree (e.g. Walls). Then you can get children node dbIds following https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/enumerating-leaf-nodes-viewer

Comment: Eason, thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I need